# Windows 8.1 Asus Laptop Keyboard not functioning

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, keyboard, asus-laptop

I changed the battery for my Asus X451C (it is exactly that, not X415CA or anything else) but then my keyboard stopped working. I currently have windows 8.1

In the control panel, in the Keyboard section, I see “This device is working properly” etc, (mind you, there is only one visible keyboard and no others in my control panel) and there are all the signs that the keyboard is not disconnected from the inside. So here is what I tried:

Entered “regedit”, when to the keyboard section, and changed Uplimitter (or something or like that) to “kbdClass” and restarted my computer. But when I opened again it had changed back
“ * * something something * * kbdClass” as you can see [here](https://youtu.be/k-TL-zhNMxo).

Next I uninstalled the only keyboard driver I have and restarted again, same problem.

**Now to make things clear, the question is WHAT DO I DO** because for some people after stating my problem they still said so what is the question. -_-

So guys please help and thnx in advance

---

**EDIT**

As gronostaj mentioned, I also tried to run the laptop on AC power only without the battery at all, and it still does not work.

Comment: Try booting without a battery and see if it helps. If yes, then new battery is the culprit (and yes, it would be weird).

Comment: @gronostaj I suspect that it is faulty because it also depleted from 100% to 55% in about an half an hour

Comment: @gronostaj The problem with the old battery was that whenever I unplugged the laptop from power it would immediately shut down. So if I run the laptop on AC power only isn't that just where I started?

Comment: Running on AC is just a test. The issue persists, so it's independent from the battery thing. Most likely a hardware failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As trivial as it may seem, it was the keyboard flat cable that was accidentally detached while changing the battery. The very first thing someone should try is that (my mistake guys sorry) or look through the control panel to see if filter keys are on, etc. If that fails, then you move to the steps I did above, which would be futile if the cable was detached the whole time (again, I'm sorry for not realising that sooner). But thanks @gronostaj for your help anyway